# Xstream absolute reference in collections

Tags: java, xstream, pojo

How can i get object from XML by using XStream, when some child in list has reference to other child in this list which placed below.
Trying:

```
<projectEstimate id="586">
    <projectEstimateKosgus class="list">

      <projectEstimateKosgu>
        <amount>1.00</amount>
        <parent class="projectEstimateKosgu" reference="/projectEstimate/projectEstimateKosgus/projectEstimateKosgu[2]"/>
        <estimate class="projectEstimate" reference="/projectEstimate"/>
      </projectEstimateKosgu>

      <projectEstimateKosgu>
        <amount>2.00</amount>
        <estimate class="projectEstimate" reference="/projectEstimate"/>
      </projectEstimateKosgu>

    </projectEstimateKosgus>
</projectEstimate>
```

projectEstimate object has collection field "projectEstimateKosgus" and childs of this collection has field "parent", which referenced on "projectEstimateKosgu" objects from this collection. When i trying to set parent in tag, which placed above of referenced tag, i get:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Invalid reference
```

But this works, if change order of "projectEstimateKosgu" tags, like this

```
<projectEstimate id="586">
    <projectEstimateKosgus class="list">

      <projectEstimateKosgu>
        <amount>2.00</amount>
        <estimate class="projectEstimate" reference="/projectEstimate"/>
      </projectEstimateKosgu>

      <projectEstimateKosgu>
        <amount>1.00</amount>
        <parent class="projectEstimateKosgu" reference="/projectEstimate/projectEstimateKosgus/projectEstimateKosgu"/>
        <estimate class="projectEstimate" reference="/projectEstimate"/>
      </projectEstimateKosgu>

    </projectEstimateKosgus>
</projectEstimate>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I think this [Object References](http://xstream.codehaus.org/graphs.html) link might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relative absolute mode` for XStream object by setting its mode as:

```
  xstream.setMode(XStream.XPATH_ABSOLUTE_REFERENCES);
```

or You can use `ID mode` for XStream object by setting its mode as:

```
  xstream.setMode(XStream.ID_REFERENCES);
```

[Reference](http://x-stream.github.io/graphs.html)

Comment: XPATH_ABSOLUTE_REFERENCES is already used.
How to use ID_REFERENCES, when projectEstimateKosgu while is a transient instance (not created)? ID's generate by hibernate when saving, and during convert from XML is unknown